# Icon Missing Dolphin

Tags: gnome, icons, dolphin

I freshly installed Ubuntu 16.04 with the Gnome environment. I installed the file browser "Dolphin" from the default repository. I ran into a problem, because when I launch it I see that there are missing icons. This can be seen [here.](http://bit.ly/21wGS9C) If you need more information to help, it is listed below:

Version of Gnome-shell: 3.18.4
Version of Dolphin: 15.12.1

Comment: Dolphin is KDE, not gnome; probably some icons from base KDE package is missing and not correctly listed in the dependency. 16.04 is beta, moreover --- so misfits are to be expected.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 has not been released yet, and as that this topic is off topic. Try installing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS or 15.10 then upgrade to 16.04 on release.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to install kde environment ... but still missing icons.

Answer (score 2):

It seems this is a know issue - see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dolphin/+bug/1509562 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kubuntu-meta/+bug/1450068

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround solution which I have tested and know works.

Solution in Cinnamon / i3 windows mangers to get GTK theme on Qt:

1. Install qt5ct
2. Set environment variable in /etc/environment or ~/.bash_profile QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct
3. Restart the system
4. Start qt5ct and select gtk2

## Install qt5ct

http://www.webupd8.org/2015/11/configure-qt5-application-style-icons.html

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install qt5ct
```

## Set up your system environment

For system wide configuration use /etc/environment, if you only have one user use ~/.bash_profile

```
echo "export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Start a new terminal or source ~/.bash_profile or reboot.

Start qt5ct select your theme
Start dolphin and everything should look ok.

Comment: Not working for me